# Why is this a topology but the the other is not?

Tags: general-topology

Given $X=\{a,b,c\}$, why is it acceptable to say that $T=\{\emptyset,X, \{a,b\}\}$ is a topology but $T=\{\emptyset,X, \{a\},\{b\}\}$ is not?

The union of $\{a\}\cup\{b\}$ is $\{a,b\}\notin T$.

So is it because $\{a,b\}\cup\{a,b,c\}$ is $X$ which is in $T$?

Do all unions of all elements in $T$ have to exist in $T$?

Comment: Yes, topologies are closed under union.

Comment: The definition of a topology is a subset of the power  set that contains the empty set, the whole set and is closed under finite intersections and arbitrary unions.  So if you have a finite intersection of elements in your topology that does not stay in the topology, it fails.  Similarly, if you have ANY union (Finite or infinite) of things in the topology that leaves the topology, it fails

Comment: "Do all unions of all elements in T have to exist in T?"  Yes, absolutely.  All unions and all finite intersections.  That's the very definition.

Comment: PS: The above is for the standard definition of a topology by defining it as the set of OPEN sets.  There's an equivalent definition of defining it by the set of CLOSED sets,  that one you just have them be closed under finite union and arbitrary intersection

Answer (score 1):

Topologies are closed under arbitrary union. Thus, if $A,B \in \tau$, then $A \cup B \in \tau$, for instance.

In your case, for $T = \{\varnothing, X, \{a\},\{b\}\}$, you have
$$
\{a\} \cup \{b\} = \{a,b\} \not \in T
$$
and thus that $T$ is not a topology.

In the case of your other topology, find all possible unions and intersections, and you'll see that each results in a set that is in this (valid) topology.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, All unions and all finite intersections must be in the Topology.

If we want to get thorough for

$T_1 = \{\emptyset, X, \{a\}, \{b\}\}$ to be a topology the following sixteen unions and sixteen intersection must be in $T_1$.

$\cup_{\emptyset} = \emptyset,\cup \emptyset = \emptyset; \cup X = X; \cup \{a\} = \{a\}, \cup \{b\}=\{b\}$
$ \emptyset \cup X = X; \emptyset \cup \{a\} = \{a\}; \emptyset\cup \{b\} =\{b\}, X\cup \{a\}=X;X\cup \{b\} = X; \color{red}{\{a\}\cup \{b\}=\{a,b\}};$
$\emptyset \cup X\cup \{a\} = X; \emptyset \cup X \cup \{b\} = X; \color{red}{\emptyset \cup \{a\}\cup \{b\} =\{a,b\}},$
$X\cup \{a\}\cup \{b\} = X; \emptyset \cup X\cup \{a\}\cup\{b\} = X$

$\cap_{\emptyset} =X,\cap \emptyset = \emptyset; \cap X = X; \cap \{a\} = \{a\}, \cap \{b\}=\{b\},$
$ \emptyset \cap X = \emptyset; \emptyset \cap \{a\} = \emptyset; \emptyset\cap \{b\} =\emptyset, X\cap \{a\}=\{a\};X\cap \{b\} = \{b\};$ ${\{a\}\cup \{b\}=\emptyset};\emptyset \cup X\cup \{a\} = \emptyset; \emptyset \cup X \cup \{b\} = \emptyset;$
${\emptyset \cup \{a\}\cup \{b\} =\emptyset},X\cup \{a\}\cup \{b\} = \emptyset; \emptyset \cup X\cup \{a\}\cup\{b\} = \emptyset$

But the $\color{red}{\{a,b\}}\not \in T_1$.

And if $T_2 = \{\emptyset, X, \{a,b\}\}$ to be a topoloty the following eight unions and eight intersections must be in $T_2$

$\cup_{\emptyset} = \emptyset;\cup \emptyset = \emptyset;\cup X = X; \cup \{a,b\} = \{a,b\}$
$\emptyset \cup X=X; \emptyset \cup \{a,b\} = \{a,b\}; X\cup \{a,b\}= X;\emptyset \cup X \cup \{a, b\} = X$

$\cap_{\emptyset} = X;\cap \emptyset = \emptyset;\cap X = X; \cap \{a,b\} = \{a,b\}$
$\emptyset \cap X=\emptyset; \emptyset \cap \{a,b\} = \emptyset; X\cap \{a,b\}=  \{a,b\};\emptyset \cap X \cap \{a, b\} = \emptyset$

and they are

....

Just in case you are wondering about the notation $\cup_{\emptyset}$ and $\cap_{\emptyset}$.  Those are my notation for the empty union and empty intersect of *no* sets.  By convention the empty union is the emptyset and the empty intersection is the universal set.